# @IsGranted annotation on property of subject

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I have annotation (working)

```
@IsGranted("editBlog", subject="company")
```

but I want something like this (not working):

```
@IsGranted("edit", subject="company.blog")
```

"Company" and "Blog" are Doctrine Entities with OneToOne relation. But my action have only "company" parameter.

```
    /**
     * @IsGranted("editBlog", subject="company")
     * @param CompanyEntity $company
       ...
     * @return Response
     */
    final public function defaultAction(
        CompanyEntity $company,
        ...
    )
    {
     ...
    }
```

How to access a variable in a subject?

Thanks!

Comment: Try with `@security("is_granted('edit', company.blog)")` or it needs `company.getBlog()`

Comment: Thanks, its working :)